# DHCPCD does not delegate an assigned IPv6 prefix

Tags: networking, ipv6, radvd, dhcpcd

I've been trying to get IPv6 PD with `dhcpcd` working on my home server along with `ppp` and `radvd` to allow for SLAAC to work and eventually replace my ISP-provided router. Unfortunately, the prefix which `dhcpcd` receives on the `ppp0` interface via RAs only gets configured as an address on that interface, instead of also being delegated to the `lan` interface on which `radvd` is operating.

What am I missing?

/etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
# Ignore changes on docker interfaces
denyinterfaces veth*

duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option interface_mtu

require dhcp_server_identifier

slaac private

noipv6rs
waitip 6
ipv6only

#Prefix Delegation
interface ppp0
option rapid_commit
ipv6rs
iaid 1
ia_pd 1/::/64 lan/0/64

#don't use ISP DNS servers
nohook resolv.conf
```

/etc/radvd.conf:

```
interface lan
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix ::/64
    {
    AdvOnLink on;
         AdvAutonomous on;
         AdvRouterAddr on;
    };
};
```

The `lan` and `wan.7` (my ISP requires VLAN 7, so this is what ppp binds to) interfaces are managed by `systemd-networkd` (DHCP is not handled by it though), but `ppp0` gets created dynamically by `ppp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old thread, but this is one of the few hits Google spits out in 2022 for configuring IPv6 PD with isc-dhcp-client, so for what it's worth:

there is a known limitation in earlier versions of isc-dhcp-client that prevents this configuration from succeding on PPPoE interfaces like ppp0. Even when all parameters are entered exactly as in the official documentation, configuration ultimately fails due to ppp0 being an "unsupported interface type" (see syslog). The problem has been addressed upstream, but as of April 2022 the fix did not yet trickle down to the more "conservative" distros like Debian 11.
Building the Package directly from upstream git will likely solve the problem, but even the official Debian Wiki recommends using alternative tools like wide-dhcp6-client instead to address the issue if you need to do prefix negotiation through PPPoE.

Comment: Thanks for answering all these years later! I noticed it working somewhat recently (I probably got the update sometime back, since the router in question is running Gentoo) and just chalked it up to my ISP finally fixing their stuff. Good to know that it was an upstream issue.